# How do I evade police brutality?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

My friendly neighborhood wild mage, unfortunately, killed a handful of commoners with an AOE Magic Missile (at least I think that's what happened.) Now, I'm only level 1/2, having just returned to Nashkel from Nashkel Mines, and an Amnish Guard caught sight of me, and decided he wanted to kill me.

The party ducked into a nearby temple of Helm and gave the gods a thousand gold pieces or so, allowing them to be respectable members of society once more, and this guard's friends aren't upset. He however, is one to hold a grudge, one which has persisted across several days of travel (Beregost and back), and loading a game after closing the program. (coming back to play the next day) I don't want to completely negate the effects of the Wild Surge by loading a game before it happened, as that seems to fly in the face of the Wild Mage playstyle, and I haven't yet found a Charm Person or similar to try; is there any way I can have peaceful relations with this guardsman? Or am I doomed to kill him and lose all my hard-bought reputation?

Comment: As a person who has never played the game this sounds completely hilarious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill the guard first - reputation has a floor at 1. Afterwards, donate to the church to raise your reputation to acceptable levels.

Comment: Won't attacking a guard, even one that's already attacking me, make all the other guards angry?

Comment: Have him follow you so you're far away from the other guards.